# Unexpected behavior of the website on two occasions. Was it under attack? Or any security risk?

Tags: wordpress, security, web

I am going to talk about two incidents.

**First:** I was developing a wordpress website and after two days, all of the sudden, I was not able to login to my website through ../wp-admin and through cpanel. And also, website was on "under construction" mode, and to my surprise, it went online. I specifically remember that I unchecked automatic end-date for under-construct mode. However, I changed my passwords and again switched on the under construction mode again.

**Second:** After few days, I tried to open my website, and got 403 error. I logged into the cpanel through the hosting and saw the permission of the index file changed to 000. I changed it back to normal. and then went to my website and there was a simple "0000000000000" on the top of the website header. I went to the file manager and saw log files(which only had three logins) and wp-load file updated on the date I never logged into the website as admin(also, the log file didn't have this login date registered). This file contained these zeros.

Now my question is:
Is my website under any attack? Or how can you describe this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that someone else is messing around with the website. Try to check the `cpanel` logs or check with the hosting provider as to when the last changes were made.

I would also advise you to do the following to ensure the security of other things that you may be using.

1. Make sure you do a full system antivirus scan your workstation and ensure that it is free from Trojans or keyloggers.
2. Remove browser extensions
3. Change your passwords & secret questions for other important sensitive accounts.
4. Scan all of your backup data as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and see if the problem persist.